# Batch processing SVG to PNG with borders

Tags: image-processing, svg, png, jpeg, imagick

I have an SVG file and I need to export it to PNG in almost 1,000,000 different sizes (height 32-1000px and width 32-1000px).

But there is a catch, the SVG image itself has a width to height ratio of 2:1.  So, when the PNG is 400x200 its an easy convert, but when the PNG is 600x200, then there needs to be a whitespace fill on the sides so that the image doesn't get distorted.

Any tools that can do this?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made [svgexport](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport) for that <s>but currently it centers and crops the output instead of padding</s> (now it supports both cropping and padding).

Answer (score 1):

Try inkscape editor. This editor is reference standard for SVG format. Inkscape has rich commandline support for exporting. More info: [INKSCAPE manual for command line export](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine-Export.html)